# Find if a uibutton exists as a subview in an uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view. Inside that view i have a uibutton. Inside the uibutton i add another smaller uibutton with the following code.

```
self.badgeIndicatorView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.friendsButton.frame.size.width-15, 5, 10, 10)];
self.badgeIndicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
BOOL doesContain = [self.friendsButton.subviews containsObject:self.badgeIndicatorView];
 
if(!doesContain){
   [self.friendsButton addSubview:self.badgeIndicatorView];
}
```

doesContain always is NO. containsObject does not seem to work. I want to check if the uibutton called `badgeIndicatorView` already exists in the `friendsButton`. What am i missing? Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you tried this 
`if(!doesContain){
self.badgeIndicatorView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.friendsButton.frame.size.width-15, 5, 10, 10)];
[self.friendsButton addSubview:self.badgeIndicatorView];
}`

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
// create a NEW button
self.badgeIndicatorView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.friendsButton.frame.size.width-15, 5, 10, 10)];
self.badgeIndicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

// friendsButton CANNOT contain the button you just created
BOOL doesContain = [self.friendsButton.subviews containsObject:self.badgeIndicatorView];
```

You would want to check if `friendsButton` *already has a subview button*.

As a side note, a better approach would be to create a subclass that adds the `badgeIndicatorView` button on init and sets it to `hidden`. Then, show or hide it as needed.

---

**Edit**

This line:

```
self.badgeIndicatorView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 100, 40)];
```

creates a ***NEW*** button and ***ASSIGNS IT*** to `self.badgeIndicatorView`.

If a button has already been created and assigned to `self.badgeIndicatorView`, the NEW button will not be equal to the old button. The old button will still exist, but will no longer be assigned to `self.badgeIndicatorView`.

Easy way to see it... run this code:

```
self.badgeIndicatorView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 100, 40)];

// log description of self.badgeIndicatorView
NSLog(@"1: %@", self.badgeIndicatorView.debugDescription);

self.badgeIndicatorView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 100, 40)];

// log description of self.badgeIndicatorView
NSLog(@"2: %@", self.badgeIndicatorView.debugDescription);

self.badgeIndicatorView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 100, 40)];

// log description of self.badgeIndicatorView
NSLog(@"3: %@", self.badgeIndicatorView.debugDescription);
```

and the debug output will look similar to this - notice that the object addresses are different (meaning you created 3 buttons):

```
1: <UIButton: 0x7f997310e310; frame = (20 10; 100 40); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002208000>>
2: <UIButton: 0x7f9951f09be0; frame = (20 10; 100 40); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002275e60>>
3: <UIButton: 0x7f99730065a0; frame = (20 10; 100 40); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002262760>>
```

So, the NEW button instance, assigned to `self.badgeIndicatorView`, will NOT be the same button instance that was already created and added to `self.friendsButton`.

You can simplify things by checking if `self.badgeIndicatorView` is not `nil` ... which would mean it was already created and added:

```
if (!self.badgeIndicatorView) {
    // create badgeIndicatorView and add it to self.friendsButton
} else {
    // badgeIndicatorView already exists!
}
```

Comment: The first time it runs it should return NO the second time it passes the code it should return YES. What do you mean i do not understand your answer...

Comment: @stefanosn - see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help, just simply adjust your code order.

```
BOOL doesContain = [self.friendsButton.subviews containsObject:self.badgeIndicatorView];
 
if(!doesContain){
   self.badgeIndicatorView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.friendsButton.frame.size.width-15, 5, 10, 10)];
   self.badgeIndicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [self.friendsButton addSubview:self.badgeIndicatorView];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're assigning a new object to your badgeIndicatorView property. The existing button cannot have it as a subview before adding it as a subview. You can use tag to identify a specific subview in the hierarchy of a view.

I'm assuming that you're trying to set the subview only once. For that, you can first check if a view with a specific tag exists in the button. If not, you can create the button, assign it the specific tag and add it as a subview. The next time, viewWithTag will give you the previously created object which is already added as a subview.

```
self.badgeIndicatorView = (UIButton *)[self.friendsButton viewWithTag:1];

if (!self.badgeIndicatorView) {
    self.badgeIndicatorView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.friendsButton.frame.size.width-15, 5, 10, 10)];
    self.badgeIndicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.badgeIndicatorView.tag = 1;

    [self.friendsButton addSubview:self.badgeIndicatorView];
}
```